# Why does the script make all the elements work simultaneously and not like they are separate objects

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a grid of products. Every product must split into 3 sub-products. I use the "Swiper" Plugin to make each product container to have 3 sub-products in it that will switch like slides when arrow is pressed, or the pagination at the bottom used.

**The problem is** that the plugin requires me to use JS for each of the products to make it work. However, my script makes all products switch their slides when only one is used actually. So they appear like they are the same object made over and over again hich is why they act like reflections of each other.

This is weird because I am using For loop and I am putting a different product container into a variable to process each time I go through a loop.

Here is the link for the plugin: https://swiperjs.com/demos/
I can't show you the full code as I can not insert the plugin into the snippet... However, here is a **detailed explanation of how all of this works:**

1. each product container has arrows to change slides and pagination at the bottom to change slides as well.
2. If the slide is changed by the arrow - the pagination is changed as well automatically.
3. At the moment if I change slides using arrows - the pagination does not change(And It is actually supposed to).
4. If I change the slide using the arrow - only the last created container will work and it will also affect and change all the other containers with it.
5. If I use the pagination to swap the slides on ANY product - all the container paginations will change and the slides will follow them.
6. So the last container works just fine. But not all the others. Though the last container still changes the others which is wrong. So if I use my code to create only 1 container - it will work perfectly...

And my HTML code with CSS in it.

```js
for (let container of document.querySelectorAll(".swiper-container")) {
  var menu = ['Slide 1', 'Slide 2', 'Slide 3']
  var mySwiper = new Swiper(container, {
    // If we need pagination
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true,
      renderBullet: function(index, className) {
        return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (menu[index]) + '</span>';
      },
    },

    // Navigation arrows
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
  })
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.products {
  display: flex;
}

.product {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 20vw;
}

.static {
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-pagination {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 0px;
  width: auto !important;
  left: auto !important;
  margin: 0;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #007aff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/5.4.3/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<div class="products">


  <button class="product">
            <div class="static">
                <!-- Slider main container -->
                <div class="swiper-container">
                    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <!-- Slides -->
                        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- If we need pagination -->
                    
                
                    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
                    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
 
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </button>

  <button class="product">
            <div class="static">
                <!-- Slider main container -->
                <div class="swiper-container">
                    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <!-- Slides -->
                        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- If we need pagination -->
                    
                
                    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
                    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
 
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </button>

  <button class="product">
            <div class="static">
                <!-- Slider main container -->
                <div class="swiper-container">
                    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <!-- Slides -->
                        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- If we need pagination -->
                    
                
                    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
                    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
 
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </button>


  <script src="swiperscript.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet

Comment: Looks fine to me. Please read more about [code snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) and provide a version of your code where we can see the problem.

Comment: Furthermore, I would suggest not using a `<button>` as a wrapper for a `<div>`. As the documentation states, permitted content is only ["Phrasing content but there must be no Interactive content"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button). Instead, you could use a `<button>` for the navigation buttons and just use `<div>` for all wrappers.